# Neo4j Built in Procedure through Cypher

Tags: neo4j, procedure

I am just started with the Procedures in Neo4j. And, wanted to look into the Built In Procedures. I ma using the community edition software. And, I have tried to list the labels in the database.

**Query:**

```
CALL db.labels()
```

**Error:**

```
Invalid input 'A': expected 'r/R' (line 1, column 2 (offset: 1))
"CALL db.labels()"
  ^
```

Do I need to run any query to make neo4j aware of this CALL command. I am simply running this in the Web Interface only.

Comment: This should work as far as I can see - which version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: 2.3.3  version of Neo4j

Comment: Yepp. Its working on 3.x vesion. Thanks

Comment: Jack can you add your last comment as an answer and accept it. It'll then show this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j 3.X+ versions support Procedures. (2.X or earlier version caused the Error). We can directly run the **CALL db.labels()** in Web Interface which in turn returns the list of labels in the Data base.

And User defined procedures cannot be created directly using cypher. Currently we can create a procedure using JAVA Api only.